# Template specialization for templated type

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have a struct that contains a trait about a type:

```
template<typename T> struct x_trait { static const bool has_x = true; };
```

That is correct for all types but for a certain template type.  For that certain template type I want to change the trait:

```
template<> struct x_trait<tt_type<int>> { static const bool has_x = false; };
```

So far, so good. But the `tt_type` itself takes different template parameters. Is there a way to set the `x_trait` for all templated `tt_type`s?  Right now my only way out is to list all types:

```
template<> struct x_trait<tt_type<char>> { static const bool has_x = false; };
template<> struct x_trait<tt_type<short>> { static const bool has_x = false; };
template<> struct x_trait<tt_type<int>> { static const bool has_x = false; };
template<> struct x_trait<tt_type<long>> { static const bool has_x = false; };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can partially specialise the `x_trait` template for all specialisations of the `tt_type` template:

```
template<typename T> 
struct x_trait<tt_type<T>> { static const bool has_x = false; };
```